# Include and neglect the text between 2 special characters

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have a string something similar to this.

`str1=r'<st-button mode="positive" width="small" can-click="{loadConference}" id="meetingPasswordButton">{{i18n "ok"}}</st-button>'`

I want to include everything between `<` and `>` and reject everything between `</` and `>`.

I tried this to include and reject the text between those special characters using following code. But I am unable to get the output. Help me cracking this situation.

code:

```
import re
pat = r'(?<=\<).+?(?=\>)' or r'(?<!\</).+?(?!\>)'   

s = r'<st-button mode="positive" width="small" can-click="{loadConference}" id="meetingPasswordButton">{{i18n "ok"}}</st-button>'


print (re.findall(pat, s))
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2276527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following regular expression will return the data between `<` and `>`:

```
print(re.findall('<((?!/).*?)>', s))
```

Output:

```
['st-button mode="positive" width="small" can-click="{loadConference}"id="meetingPasswordButton"']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'<st-button mode="positive" width="small" can-click="{loadConference}" id="meetingPasswordButton">{{i18n "ok"}}</st-button>'
>>> print re.findall(r'<([^\/].*?)>', s)
['st-button mode="positive" width="small" can-click="{loadConference}" id="meetingPasswordButton"']
```